# Opening windows application (media player) using php

Tags: php, windows, media-player

I have written a .php script. When there is some event, it writes to a file. It's working perfectly!
Now I want to open Windows Media Player or any other player using this php script as I also want to play a sound when the event occurs. I tried embedding the sound file as follow:
    echo "< embed src =\"$file\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\">";
But it only writes to the file n do not play the audio, when the event occurs.
I came across 'exec' command which didnt work. (I am not sure about how it works. An example would be a great help!)
Does anyone know how to start a windows application using php script?

EDIT REMOVED

Thanks,
Sagar.

Comment: post the generated code (according to you, the "written" code).

Comment: My written php code is as follows: <?php
   $msg = $_GET["Message"];
   echo $msg;
   $fp = fopen('TestCamMsg.txt', 'w');
   fwrite($fp,$msg);
   
   $file='bell1.mp3';
   echo exec('C:\\Program Files\\Windows Media player\\wmplayer.exe', $out);
   echo exec('bell1.mp3', $out);
   print_r($out);

Comment: I also tried $output = ` C:\wamp\www\wmpstart.bat ` ;
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; 
which some people said worked for them. But it isnt working for me. When I run the script, it only displays path to wmpstart.bat file n shows its contents. (I am using WAMPSERVER 2.2.) Any guesses why it isnt working?

Answer (score 1):

You can play a wave file in your server side folder in a php file by adding this 
`<?php exec('c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\website\beep.wav');
?>`

and this would play the beep.wav usually through whatever sound appy is installed on your machine, like windows media player.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start console based application through Apache+PHP application. The reason is, as Apache webserver is running as a system service in a separate logon session, it cannot start UI based applications which requires a login console session.

Anyway, you can embed the audio inside the html page. Refer the http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp page to get more details.

Comment: 1. "running as a system service" -- depends on the configuration. 2. "w3schools" -- lolwhut?

Comment: @k102 omg... now I understand :) I never took seriously w3schools

Answer (score 0):

Comment about running Windows GUI programs using PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php#87943

But, I think you only need to embed player on your page using some HTML tag as Aravind described.

Comment: Thanks! But I did embed the player, but when client machine runs this php script, it cant play the embed player as it doesnt involve any activity with browser. I want my client machine to execute commands which will play audio on my server machine. any idea about how to do this?

Comment: Are you running your PHP script in CLI?

Answer (score 0):

SagarJ,

You can embed the audio file in html and will be executed by the browser/browser plugin application already installed in the system.

So, you need not to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks. But as I mentioned, I embedded the audio file, but it doesnt play that audio when the event occurs, though it runs the script. That's why I want to run a batch file which will deal with runniing windows applications.